# Edit a specific User attribute in a page in Concrete5

Tags: attributes, custom-attributes, concrete5

My concrete 5.6.3.1 site has public registration. I have attribute called "I am a ambassador", which is a checkbox that shows in registration and in your profile.
 My question is i need this particular attribute to be shown and can be edited inside a specific page.

For Eg: I have a page called Sing up as Ambassador, when going to this page i need to show this particular check box which the user can enable/disable it and save it.(same as profile edit). Anybody there to help me?

Comment: What version of concrete5?

Comment: # concrete5 Version
5.6.3.1

Answer (score 2):

## NOTICE: This answer is for legacy concrete5 version 6, only some of it will apply for version 7

So for this question, there are a few parts that we'll need to go over.

1. How do I determine the current logged in user?

   ```php
   $user = new User();
   $user_info = UserInfo::getByID($user->getUserID());
   ```
2. How do I get an attribute value?

   ```php
   $user_info->getAttribute('my_attribute_handle');
   ```
3. How do I set an attribute value?

   ```php
   $user_info->setAttribute('my_attribute_handle', $value);
   ```

So then in my singlepage **view method**, I'll have something like:

```php
public function view()
{
    $user = new User();
    $some_attribute = false;
    if ($user->isLoggedIn()) {
        $user_info = UserInfo::getByID($user->getUserID());
        $some_attribute = $user_info->getAttribute('some_attribute');
    }
    $this->set('some_attribute', $some_attribute);
}
```

And then in my singlepage **view file**, I have:

```php
<input type='checkbox' value='1' name='some_attribute' <?= $some_attribute ? 'checked' : '' ?> />
```

Where ever my form ends up submitting, I'll do this:

```php
$user = new User();
if ($user->isLoggedIn()) {
    $user_info = UserInfo::getByID($user->getUserID());
    $user_info->setAttribute('some_attribute', $_REQUEST['some_attribute'] == 1);
}
```